# Keras regression - Should my first/last layer have an activation function?

Tags: keras

I keep seeing examples floating around the internet where the input and/or output layer have either no activation function, a linear activation function, or `None`. What I'm confused about is when to use one, and how to know if you should? I also am confused about what the number of nodes should be for the input layer.

Right now I have a regression problem, I'm trying to predict a real value based on an array of inputs (about 54). Should I be using `relu` in my activation function for the input layer? Should I have `linear` as my output activation? My data is linearly scaled from 0 to 1 for each feature independently as they're different units. I was also unsure of the number of nodes I should use for my input layer as I see some examples pick an arbitrary number not related to their input shape, and other examples saying to specifically set it to the number of inputs, or number of inputs plus one for a bias. But none of the examples so far have explained their reasoning behind their choices.

Since my model isn't performing very well, I thought asking what the architecture *should* be could help me fine tune it more.

Comment: As you have a regression problem to solve, you should use a linear activation on your last layer.

Comment: About the first layer, I do not know what kind of architecture you are bulding, but, for example, in a Dense layer, if you do not explicitly define an activation function, the identity will be applied.

ReLU or ELU are good candidates for activation functions if you have a deep network, because of the [Vanishing Gradient Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_gradient_problem). If you network is small, you could use sigmoid or hyperbolic tanget as well.

Comment: @RicardoYamamotoAbe Gotcha, so None and 'linear' are the same. That's what I figured. I'm going to just leave it linear and see what I can tune from there. I've always used ReLU for regression, but I'm going to try and experiment with ELU and PRELU to see what the results are. For some reason, tanh and sigmoid activations always make the model quickly stop learning at a high loss, and ReLU has always been the most consistent. Thanks for the tips!